# Convert from decimal to ASCII the data present in a column of a .csv file

Tags: powershell, ascii

i should convert the data of a column of a csv file in powershell
This data is often in decimal and I would need to convert it to ASCII as in the example

80, 77, 79, 32, 83, 50, 52, 50, 45, 86, 70, 67   **-> to Ascii >**  PMO S242-VFC

the table is composed as follows

| Monitor | Modello |
| --- | --- |
| wkst1 | 80, 77, 79, 32, 83, 50, 52, 50, 45, 86, 70, 6 |
| wkst2 | V246HL |
| wkst3 | V256IL |
| wkst4 | 65, 99, 101, 114, 32, 86, 50, 52, 54, 72, 76 |

this is the result

| Monitor | Modello |
| --- | --- |
| wkst1 | PMO S242-VFC |
| wkst2 | V246HL |
| wkst3 | V256IL |
| wkst4 | Acer V246HL |

Thanks

Comment: What did you try? [`Encoding.GetString`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.encoding.getstring?view=net-7.0) should get you going if you don't know where to start.

Comment: request not clear at all....

Comment: Please show us part of the csv file **AS-IS**. Open it in Notepad, copy the first 3 or 4 lines and then paste these in as [formatted text](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) in your queston. (click the [edit] link). That way we can see what delimiter character the file uses and what character separates the byte array in the Modello field.

Answer (score 0):

You need to iterate your CSV file rows, and check each row, if the row is a `Byte` Data row, convert it using: `[System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetString`

So for example:

```
foreach ($row in Import-Csv c:\filepath.csv)
{
    if ($row.Modello -is [array] # just an example, needs more validation
    {
    [System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetString([byte]$Row.Modello) # save it somewhere
    }
}
```

As you did not provided any code or showing your work, I'm just showing an example of what you can probably do,